# Detecting if an HTML checkbox was selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have created the following jQuery script  to check if my "chkboxAdd" checkbox has been clicked or not.

```
    (function ( $ ){
        $.fn.myfunction = function(){
            $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() 
            {      
                if($(this).attr('name') == 'chkboxAdd' && $(this).attr('checked') == true   )
                {

                    alert('Checkbox add is checked!');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    alert('Checkbox add is NOT checked!');
                 }
            });
        };   
    })(jQuery);
```

However after clicking the "chkboxAdd" checkbox, the alert prompt always go on the else clause instead of the if clause and prompts:

```
            Checkbox add is NOT checked!
```

I have included the relevant HTML snippets for reference. Thank you in advance.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() 
     {
         $('#chkBoxTable').myfunction();
     } ); 
</script>

                    <table id="chkBoxTable" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><strong>Page ID</strong></th>
                                    <th><strong>Page Name</strong></th>
                                    <th><strong>Action</strong></th>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                    <?php
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["PAGEID"]; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["PAGENAME"]; ?></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkboxAdd" value="add">Add</td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: use `prop()` for `checked` not `attr()`

Comment: `if ($(this).is(":checked"))`

Comment: In the future, it can help to narrow down your if statement to see which part of the expression is failing. By doing that you would see that `$(this).attr('checked')` is returning false even when it was checked and been able to do a quick search to see what the proper way to get if a checkbox is checked... thereby saving yourself the time of asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).attr('checked')
```

Should be

```
$(this).prop('checked')
```

since you want the property `checked`, not the attribute. Getting the attribute would determine whether or not the check box has the actual attribute of `checked`, which would not change from regular user input.

Example, if the page started with the check box checked then `$(this).attr('checked')` would be true, but if the user unchecked the box, it would still equal true.